# PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = text[]

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Looking resolution in postgres DB and MySQL DB working fine

I/P: String ordIds = "343,21,343";

Map fetchDataSource(String orgIds){

```
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    String str[] = orgIds.split(",");
    List<Integer> orgIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Map<String, String> dataSourceMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    orgIdList = Arrays.asList(str).stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    String query = "select ds.ds_path,string_agg(org.organization_id::text, ',') as org_id from c_organization org join org_ds_detail ds on org.org_ds_detail_id = ds.org_ds_detail_id where org.organization_id in (?) GROUP BY ds.ds_path";
    //String queryIN = orgIdList.stream().map(orgId -> String.valueOf(orgId)).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "(", ")"));

    try {
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getInstance("CLINICS_GLOBAL");
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        **Array orgIdsInArray = connection.createArrayOf("text",orgIdList.toArray());
        statement.setArray(1, orgIdsInArray);**
        logger.info("Executing Query:" + query);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            dataSourceMap.put(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info("Exception:" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
            resultSet.close();
            DBConnection.closeConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.info("Exception while closing connection:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return dataSourceMap;
}
```

Exception (Logs):

```
13:16:16,217 INFO  [DataSourceConnection] (default task-2) Exception:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = text[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 190
13:16:16,219 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = text[]
13:16:16,219 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
13:16:16,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   Position: 190
13:16:16,221 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the error message says, you are passing a `text[]` array and trying to compare that with a `bigint` value. Would you expect the `Long.valueOf(1) == new String[] {"1", "2"}` to work in Java?

You need to create a bigint array:

```
Array orgIdsInArray = connection.createArrayOf("bigint",orgIdList.toArray());
```

And you need to change your operator that compares the column with the array:

```
where org.organization_id = any (?)
```

---

Another option that doesn't involve creating an `java.sql.Array` would be to convert the comma separated list to an array in SQL, rather than in Java. For that change your SQL statement to:

```
where org.organization_id = any (string_to_array(?, ',')::bigint[])
```

And then simply pass the original string to the PreparedStatement:

```
statement.setString(1, orgIds);
```

Then you can get rid of converting the String to an array and then to a List in Java.